# Заполнение ячейки по высоте

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Есть такая табличка:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-4">
    тут<br>какое<br>то<br>описание
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2">
    <div class="load">тут</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2">
    <div class="load">подгружаемые</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2">
    <div class="load">блоки</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2">
    <div class="load">разной</div>
    <div class="load">высоты</div>
</div>
```

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Lht5ewd7/1/)
Ее содержимое подгружается динамически (от 1 до 4х блоков).

Необходимо сделать следующее:
1. Загруженные блоки должны занимать всю полезную площадь (если загрузился 1 то 100% высоты, если 2 - 50% и т.д.);
2. Содержимое этих блоков должно выравниваться по высоте;
3. Если, например после загрузки одна из ячеек увеличила высоту строки, то в остальных, уже загруженных ячейках, высота всех блоков должна подогнаться под новую высоту строки.

Чисто CSS у меня не получилось, пытаюсь сделать при помощи JS (после каждой подгрузки проверяю текущее количество блоков в ячейке и устанавливаю статическую высоту), но работает очень криво.
Да и есть подозрения, что есть вариант получше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте flexbox.
Родительскому контейнеру задайте свойства:

```
.parent {
display:flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-content: stretch;
}
.child {
flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Именно свойство стретч здесь определяющее. Позволяет дочерним блокам растягиваться равномерно.
Можно ещё задать блокам дочерним свойство flex-grow: 1; это позволит им делить свободное пространство равномерно.